# Something keeps changing the default permissions of my settings.php file for a web site on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I keep changing the file permissions for the file  /var/www/html/websitename/settings.php to 775 and within 15 minutes or so it automatically changes back 555.

The owner of the file is "apache" and the group ownership is for our Linux Developers just like all of the other files which are not having this issue.

Obviously there must be some sort of process running that is automatically changing the file permissions (apache maybe?) but I haven't been able to figure out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that it's not the web application itself that's changing the permissions? grep the source for `chmod`.